# Calling overridden method in super module in Ruby

Tags: ruby, methods, module, super

In the following code, `Parent#just_do` overrides `GrandParent#just_do`. In the `Me` class, how do I call `GrandParent#just_do`?

```
module GrandParent
  def just_do
    puts "GrandParent"
  end
end

module Parent
  def self.included(base)
    base.extend ClassMethods
  end

  module ClassMethods
    include GrandParent

    def just_do
      puts "Parent"
    end
  end
end

class Me
  include Parent

  def self.just_do
    super # this calls Parent#just_do
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't really un-override something. In this particular case you could re-import it, but that could have other side-effects.

It's probably best for the "Parent" to preserve the original because it may need to be called:

```
module GrandParent
  def just_do
    puts "GrandParent"
  end
end

module Parent
  def self.included(base)
    base.extend ClassMethods
  end

  module ClassMethods
    include GrandParent

    # Creates an alias to the original method
    alias_method :grandpa_just_do, :just_do
    def just_do
      puts "Parent"
    end
  end
end

class Me
  include Parent

  def self.just_do
    # Call using the alias created previously
    grandpa_just_do
  end
end

Me.just_do
```

Answer (score 6):

You could work with the [method object](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.1/Method.html) directly.

```
class Me
  include Parent

  def self.just_do
    method(:just_do).super_method.super_method.call
  end
end
```

Comment: Well, it'd be whatever Parent overrode

Comment: The difference being that you can have multiple layers in the middle as long as they don't also override the same method

Comment: @XingangHuang, when the number of "layers" is unknown, but the module that is the owner of the method to be invoked is known, you can write something like the following (unrelated to the present problem). `module A; def x; 'A'; end; end; module B; def x; 'B'; end; end; module C; def x; 'C'; end; end; class Y; include A, B, C; def z(c); m = method(:x); while m.owner != c; m = m.super_method; end; m.call; end; end`. Then for `y = Y.new`, `y.z(A) #=> 'A'; y.z(B) #=> 'B'; y.z(C) #=> 'C'`.